# Ubuntu 12.04 latest update completely crippled system

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, login

I am dualbooting with Windows 8.1 x64 and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. Currently only able to use my Windows as my Ubuntu boot was crippled by this evening's update. The update was with lots of packages and so I am unsure which one and why crippled my installation.

I am unable to boot normally or login. Grub is loading OK, but afterwards something happens and I cannot pinpoint the issue. As soon as Ubuntu's pre-logon screen comes up (and I have to mention it comes with the wrong resolution) it goes away and the following lines appear:

```
Starting anac(h)ronistic cron                    OK
Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron                    OK
```

Then I am greeted with the shell logon option. I am able to logon, but the command startx gives me black screen and I cannot go back from it.

**EDIT Start:**

Forgot to say - my shell logon now claims that I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, and I have not been prompted or agreed on any dist-upgrade. Also, I thought 12.04.4 was not going to come out until 16 Feb...?

The new drivers that were installed are nvidia-updates-331 version 331.20.

**EDIT End.**

I tried recovery and it kind of worked once. I chose recovery from grub and then resume normal boot. Then it got me to the normal logon screen, but here is the funny thing. I enter my password, Ubuntu accepts it, plays the logon sound, the screen goes blank and then I am returned to the logon screen again to enter my password. And this repeats in an infinite loop... Although, I can easily logon with the Guest account, but I am unable to do anything with it, since I have never used or configured it before.

I tried running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` from the shell, but it had no effect. I looked at the new xorg.conf and it is identical to the previous one except for the version number of the drivers, but this line is commented anyway.

I tried grub repair, but that did not work as well.

I tried logging in though an older kernel - nope.

Basically, everything that came to mind and I know of, I have tried and it did not have any effect whatsoever on my situation.

Please help! I have some work to do and I would rather not do it in Windows...

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT 2:**

I am not sure how, but this update appears to have cleared some BIOS settings. Also, my wifi card was disabled, so I had to re-enable it manually in the BIOS. Does anybody have any idea what could be going on?

**EDIT 3:**

Moved my `.config` folder out of the way as suggested, but no result. Fixed the BIOS settings, turn out it is something else unrelated. But now there is something else. This `[   3.106484] 4:3:1: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86` appears on the black screen after the GUI fails and just before the shell logon pops up.

**EDIT 4:**

Unfortunately, I do not have much more time for experimentation and if I can't find a solution soon I will be reinstalling Ubuntu. I have regained some usability through the shell interface, but GUI only loads for the guest account still. I'll planning on saving my $HOME on another drive and starting clean in a couple of days. What a shame...

Comment: Point-releases are not pushed out as new distribution releases; they filter through as normal (non-security) updates to the original distribution.

Comment: Well, I'm sure I don't have 12.04.4, since it's not coming until 16 Feb. I was aiming at using this info to pinpoint the error.

Comment: My system claims to be 12.04.4 too, I saw some updates pushed recently that will have updated the version number.

Comment: If you're using the nvidia proprietary drivers, I might be tempted to boot in recovery mode, drop to a root shell, and switch back to nouveau in /etc/X11/xorg.conf, at least as temporary measure. At least that way you should get a usable desktop from which you can dig further into the problems with relative ease ..

Comment: I don't think it is the driver, since the guest account has no problem loading GUI. Drivers in my opinion work with no problem.

Comment: My Ubuntu has 12.04.4

Answer (score 0):

When you say you can logon to the Guest account OK, do you mean you can access the desktop and all normal system functions successfully? If so that would imply that there is something in your user settings that is causing the problem.

If you can run a terminal from Guest mode, you should be able to "su " to access your normal account. From there you could e.g. move your .config directory out of the way (e.g. to .config.bak) and see if that enables you to login, or add a new user account and copy your data/documents to that without copying the settings.

Comment: Yes, I can access the guest account no problem, but `su` returns an error saying that guest cannot execute that command. The same goes for `sudo` and `sudo su`. Also, guest account access doesn't happen all the time, only when it lets me. I will keep trying though.

Comment: I was able to move my .config folder from shell, but it didn't change the situation.

Comment: My bad .. 12.04 seems to disable setgid privileges for the guest session, which messes up su. This used to work from a guest account in prior versions. The dir that might be worth moving out of the way is .gconf, but if access even from the Guest account is patchy, that implies something else is the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with the update today. Since this is the second time within three weeks, I just uninstalled the nvidia.304 package, and everything works fine again.

Last time, the nvidia packet was claiming that dependencies are not met, and some libs are missing. I didn't check this time.

My system: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 64 bit, Quattro FX 580

Comment: I will try that first thing when I get home. I'm currently on the road for some time

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work. I still think it's not a driver issue as the guest GUI has no problem loading.